# "Врасплох"

Tags: этимология

Пытаюсь осознать этимологию слова "врасплох", но никак не могу уловить. Вижу только корень "плох".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит **врасплох**? Неожиданно, внезапно, так, чтобы напугать. Есть фразеологизм *застать врасплох*, т.е. *всполошить*. Есть в русском языке и такие слова: *всполошиться*, *сполохнутый* (разг.), *переполох*.

В словаре Фасмера находим слово ПОЛОХ. Ближайшая этимология: род.п. -оха, *полошить*, *переполох*, укр. полох "страх", полох "ужас", блр. полох "испуг", др.-русск. полошити "пугать", русск.-цслав. плахъ "страх". Кроме того, во многих славянских языках есть родственные слова с похожей семантикой. В соответствии с правилами исторической фонетики находим праславянское соответствие *роlхъ; вероятно, родственно греч. pallo "возбуждаю, потрясаю", родственное слову* полемика *от греч. polemos 'война'. В комментарии О.Н.Трубачева приводится версия, согласно которой слав.* роlхъ происходит от и.-е. *реl-/*роl- "двигаться" при семантическом развитии "бегство" > "страх".

Слово **ПЛОХОЙ** имеет такую ближайшую этимологию: плох, плоха, плохо, укр. плохий "смирный, тихий, кроткий", блр. плохi "болезненный, плохой", др.-русск. плохъ "плохой", чеш. рlосhy "плоский", но польск. рłосhу "пугливый; ветреный; суетный". Скорее связано с ***полох***. Сюда же, с др. ступенью вокализма, *плаха*.

Как видите, этимологически слова ВРАСПЛОХ и ПЛОХОЙ, возможно, и родственники, но корня "плох" в современном значении в слове ВРАСПЛОХ нет.

Тем не менее, от испуга, конечно, ничего хорошего тоже ждать не приходится :-)

Answer (score 1):

образовано от слова "полошить"-пугать, волновать. 
Выпала одна гласная, как в словах "город-град". Добавили приставки в- (в значении "внутрь"), рас- (в значении "открыть"), что усиливает действие и даёт новое значение "раскрыть волнение внутри" и, в итоге, получилось слово "врасплох"- неожиданно, внезапно испугать, заставить волноваться.